# Plotting Single Covariate Regression Line in a Multivariate Model

Tags: r

I am able to create a multivariate linear regression model using

```
lmex = lm(overweight$h_egfr_cystc96 ~ overweightlogblood + overweight$age_96, data = overweight)
```

Which returns values for the intercept, estimate, p-value, etc.

I want to plot a single regression line for one of my variables: `overweightlogblood`

If I use

```
ggplot(overweight,aes(y=h_egfr_cystc96,x=overweightlogblood))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

It gives me a nice plot, but this is for the ***univariate*** model. I would like the plot to feature a regression line (with 95% CI) for the intercept and estimate of a single covariate in a ***multivariate*** model. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!